# New Angular Project does not include e2e folder

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I had Angular already on my system and had briefly worked with it around 7-8 months ago.

A short while ago, I created a new Angular project

```
ng new testproject
```

The strange part is that the e2e folder was not created!

I tried uninstalling the CLI, clearing the cache and reinstalling Angular.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

But this has not worked.

This is the output of  `ng --version`:

[image]

This is what the folder looks like:

[image]

Comment: [_"We've opted to not include \[Protractor\] in new projects..."_](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v12-is-now-available-32ed51fbfd49)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> The Future of Protractor
>
> The Angular team has been working with the community to determine the future of Protractor. We’re currently reviewing the feedback shared in the RFC. We’re still figuring out the best future for Protractor. **We’ve opted to not include it in new projects and, instead, provide options with popular 3rd party solutions in the Angular CLI.** We are currently working with Cypress, WebdriverIO, and TestCafe to help users adopt the alternative solutions. More information to come as this develops.

https://blog.angular.io/angular-v12-is-now-available-32ed51fbfd49

Answer (score 3):

Try this:  open command line interface, go to directory of your project (ex:hello-world), and type:

`ng e2e [project]`.

For Example: `(ng e2e hello-world)` This will build it for you.