# I cant find e2e folder in my angular project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[image: e2e]

Also reinstalled CLI but still couldn't find E2E.

Comment: Protractor is being deprecated, Angular CLI apps no longer come with e2e by default. See https://blog.angular.io/angular-v12-is-now-available-32ed51fbfd49.

Comment: You can add cypress using their schematics https://github.com/briebug/cypress-schematic

Comment: You could get your answer from this similar post: [New Angular Project does not include e2e folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67620400/new-angular-project-does-not-include-e2e-folder)

Answer (score 1):

**Protractor is being deprecated**, so newer Angular versions don't come with e2e folder.

In my opinion the best replacement for it is **Cypress**.

Here's a link https://docs.cypress.io/guides/migrating-to-cypress/protractor#Introduction to Cypress documentation where you can find how to migrate from **Protractor** to **Cypress**.